# Highcharter Map with Categorical Variables in R

Tags: r, highcharts

I am trying to use the highcharts wrapper `highcharter` in R to create a series of maps.  Maps that plot state or country color to a continuous variable work beautifully, however, I'm having some trouble plotting state color to a continuous variable.  (Basically, I'd like it to look something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6ubtyu3b/24/)).

I've tried everything that I can think of and nothing seems to work.  Here's an example with dummy data.  Assume that I want to show states in category A as red, category B as yellow and category C as blue.

```
library("dplyr")
library('highcharter')
library("viridisLite") 

data(usgeojson)

## Create data frame with letter categories, numerical categories, and state abbreviations

categories <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "A", "B",
"B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B",
"B", "B", "B", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B" )

states <- c("AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI",
"ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS",
"MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR",
"PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY")

numbers <- c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1",
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2",
"2", "2", "2", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2",
"2", "2", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2" )

data <- data.frame(categories, states, numbers)

## Convert abbreviations to state names for highcharter
data$state_full <- state.name[match(data$state, state.abb)]

## If we plot these data using the numerical categories, the colors are on a scale
highchart(type = "map") %>% 
hc_add_series_map(map = usgeojson, 
                df = data, 
                joinBy = c("woename", "state_full"),
                value = "numbers")

## Plotting by adding each category individually ends up with the each new map
## overwriting the ones before it. 

cat_A <- data[data$categories == "A", ]
cat_B <- data[data$categories == "B", ]
cat_C <- data[data$categories == "C", ]

highchart(type = "map") %>% 
hc_add_series_map(map = usgeojson, 
                df = cat_A, 
                joinBy = c("woename", "state_full"),
                value = "numbers") %>% 
hc_add_series_map(map = usgeojson, 
                df = cat_B, 
                joinBy = c("woename", "state_full"),
                value = "numbers") %>% 
hc_add_series_map(map = usgeojson, 
                df = cat_C, 
                joinBy = c("woename", "state_full"),
                value = "numbers")
```

This clearly can work in highcharts but I can't seem to get it to work in highcharter.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Interesting - unrelated but when I run this I am now getting error that `object 'usgeojson' not found`. Tested against my other highcharter map type projects and they fail also. Ah, I fat fingered it. Maps load now. But yes, they are monochromatic still.

Comment: Oh! Sorry about that! I edited the script and added the necessary `data(usgeojson)` call.

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution for the issue? I also have the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

States from third series that doesn't have data are displayed as grey states and are over the data from previous series. You could set [`allAreas`](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/plotOptions.series.allAreas) to `false` to prevent this.

Additionally colorAxis needs to get max setting, because it is automatically calculated for the first series only - [the issue reported](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6209).

Working code (to run after your code - after categories are set):

```
highchart(type = "map") %>% 
hc_plotOptions(series = list(allAreas = F)) %>%
hc_colorAxis(max = 3) %>%
hc_add_series_map(map = usgeojson, 
                df = cat_A, 
                joinBy = c("woename", "state_full"),
                value = "numbers") %>% 
hc_add_series_map(map = usgeojson, 
                df = cat_B, 
                joinBy = c("woename", "state_full"),
                value = "numbers") %>% 
hc_add_series_map(map = usgeojson, 
                df = cat_C, 
                joinBy = c("woename", "state_full"),
                value = "numbers")
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replicate the example that you want.

```
cat_A <- data %>% filter(categories == "A")
cat_B <- data %>% filter(categories == "B")
cat_C <- data %>% filter(categories == "C")

map <- download_map_data("countries/us/us-all")

hc <- highchart(type = "map") %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(map = list(
    allAreas = FALSE,
    joinBy = c("hc-a2", "states"),
    mapData = map
  )) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "A", data = cat_A, color = "#A1A1A1") %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "B", data = cat_B, color = "#46BEC8") %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "C", data = cat_C, color = "#0000CD")

hc
```

Other alternative:

```
series <- data %>% 
  group_by(name = categories) %>% 
  do(data = list_parse(select(., states))) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(color = c("red", "darkred", "pink"))

series

highchart(type = "map") %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(map = list(
    allAreas = FALSE,
    joinBy = c("hc-a2", "states"),
    mapData = map
  )) %>% 
  hc_add_series_list(series)
```