# How to create layer filters on a map using Highcharts?

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I have a map similar to this: `https://www.highcharts.com/demo/maps/us-counties`

1. I want to create a layer filter showing different income groups at the county level, similar to this demo:
   `https://www.highcharts.com/demo/maps/data-class-two-ranges`

I tried to replicate the code from the data class demo, using hc_add_series for each layer. but how do I keep the choropleth color scale?

2. When you click on the legend feature, Trump states gets deactivate. I would like to do the same but with income groups in the choropleth map.
3. I also would like to hover over a county have its information displayed, regardless of which layer is available. Right now, if I have all layers activated, I can only hover over the latest layer.
4. The way I coded this example (and my original code with 3 layers) is VERY slow and redundant. How do I simplify it and make the run time faster?

Below is my code - for some reason group 1 and group 2 layers are not showing correctly as well.

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)

n <- nrow(unemployment)

unemployment <- unemployment %>% 
                mutate(group = rbinom(n,1,.5))

grp1 <- unemployment %>% filter(group == 1)
grp2 <- unemployment %>% filter(group == 0)

hcmap("countries/us/us-all-all"
      , data = unemployment
      , opacity = .4
      , joinBy = c("hc-key", "code")
      , name = "unemployment rate"
      , borderColor = "#FAFAFA"
      , nullColor = "#d3d3d3"
      , borderWidth = 0.1
) %>% 
  hc_add_series_map(
    name = "Group 1",
    showInLegend = TRUE,   
    map = uscountygeojson,
    df = grp1,
    borderWidth = 0.1,
    value = "value",
    joinBy = c("hc-key", "code"),
    nullColor = "transparent",
    color = "#F28E2B",
    states = list(
      hover = list(
        color = "#A4EDBA"
      )),
    tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 1, 
                   valueSuffix = "%",
                   pointFormat = "{point.name}: {point.value}")
) %>% 
  hc_add_series_map(
    name = "Group 2",
    showInLegend = TRUE,   
    map = uscountygeojson,
    df = grp1,
    borderWidth = 0.1,
    value = "value",
    joinBy = c("hc-key", "code"),
    nullColor = "transparent",
    color = "#F28E2B",
    states = list(
      hover = list(
        color = "#A4EDBA"
      )),
    tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 1, 
                   valueSuffix = "%",
                   pointFormat = "{point.name}: {point.value}")    
) %>% 
  hc_title(
    text = "US Counties Unemployment Rate"
  ) %>% 
  hc_legend(
    layout = "vertical",
    align = "right",
    floating = TRUE,
    backgroundColor = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85"
  ) %>% 
  hc_mapNavigation(
    enabled = TRUE
  ) %>% 
  hc_colorAxis(
    min = 0,
    max = 25,
    tickInterval = 5,
    stops = list_parse2(
      tibble(
        q = c(0, .65,  1), 
        c = c("#500007", "#900037", "#F1EEF6")
        
      )
    ),
    labels = list(
      format = "{value}%"
    )
  ) %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(
      mapline = list(
      showInLegend = FALSE,
      enableMouseTracking = FALSE
    )
) %>% 
  hc_tooltip(
    valueDecimals = 1,
    valueSuffix = "%"
  ) %>% 
  hc_credits(
    enabled = TRUE
  ) %>% 
  hc_exporting(
    enabled = TRUE
  )
```

I am new to using highcharter and don't know much about javascript. I don't know how to translate javascript documentation to R. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your code with some sample data?

Comment: This is similar to this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877282/highcharter-map-with-categorical-variables-in-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877282/). I can't seem to add the choropleth colors with the code suggested in the question.